# Compile-time error for NotSupportedException in subclass function

Tags: c#, exception, inheritance

If I have a subclass that has yet to implement a function provided by the base class, I can override that function and have it throw a `NotSupportedException`.  Is there a way to generate a compile-time error for this to avoid only hitting this at runtime?

Update: I can't make the base class abstract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Obsolete("This still needs implementing", true/false)] true if you don't want the build to succeed, false if you just want a warning

Slightly hackish ... but it does the job of warning at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the base class abstract:

```
abstract class Foo
{
    public abstract void Bar();
}
```

Now, any subclass must implement `Bar()`, or it won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Make it abstract with no implementation and fail to implement it in the derived class.